# java joptsimple Getting two options with arguments

Tags: java, parameters

I'm using the joptsimple library but I can't seem to load arguments in this fashion:

```
java Program -p P-File -a A-File
```

I'm using the following code to load the options:

```
OptionParser parser = new OptionParser("p:a:");
OptionSet options = parser.parse("-p", "-a");

if(options.has("p") && options.hasArgument("p")) {
    //Load with FileInputStream
}
if(options.has("a") && options.hasArgument("a")) {
    //Load with FileInputStream
}
```

My code can load -p file fine, but can't find the -a File

Comment: Are you sure that your code ever finishes loading the `-p` file? Please show more code if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when trying to create the OptionSet instead of parsing ("p", "a") I was suppose to be parsing the args from main(String[] args). Problem sovled.